# Is there any way we could use the VS designers for SP Content Types, Lists, etc. in non-standard SP or SP Apps VS project templates?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-templates

We are interested in making some custom VS project templates for our developers and this would be a great help.  More specifically, we want to create a unified starter VS project template for new SharePoint developers that could target both full trust solutions, CSOM/JSOM, and REST to build/deploy IA to both SharePoint and SharePoint Online.  The idea is to add/manage common frameworks and utility classes for our newer developers so that we are always utilizing an updated managed VS project template, no matter what the project requirements dictate.

So is there any way we could use the VS designers for Content Types, Lists, and other SharePoint elements in non-standard SharePoint or SharePoint Apps VS project templates?

Comment: To clarify: Are you talking about being able to have a set template for all developers to use every time they develop solutions or are you talking about referencing specific existing code/resources that is referenced as needed but not necessarily in the solution from the start?

Comment: @Graham "a set template for all developers to use every time they develop solutions"...yes for all developers in our organization.  "referencing specific existing code/resources that is referenced as needed but not necessarily in the solution from the start"...no, it needs to be in the solution when the project is started, but the template its based on could be maintained over time to add/update/remove code assets/components.  Either way, my question isn't about that.  **My question is soley on being able to use the VS designers in non-SharePoint based VS project templates**.

Comment: You can create [project templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) easily enough if you know everything that needs to be included in a project (assuming you don't have those things built into a site Master Page or use them in page templates. Which Visual Studio designers that are specific to SharePoint are you referring to?